# Resarch Paper on Conceptual Design of a Physical System

Tags: research-topic

Is a paper acceptable if it is based on a concept design of a physical system backed by some mathematical models and simulations? No practical development and experimentation is present.
In other words, **"Is an argument based on just mathematical models and matlab simulations acceptable as a research article?"**
If *YES*, then would it be worthy of an impact factor journal or just a low level conference?

Comment: What does your advisor think?

Comment: He thinks it might be passable but he's not really sure. I just want an opinion from someone who might have an experience with something similar (maybe someone who has reviewed a lot of papers of different statures eg.)

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is a yes/no answer to your question, at least not without someone from your field to review your contribution. After some time in academia, you will begin to get a sense of what is publishable and what is not. As a new student (I assumed you are), this is the role of your supervisor. 
While it is not the same question, the following question shares almost the same concern as yours. You might find it helpful.

[How can I efficiently check the originality of my work?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/141981/how-can-i-efficiently-check-the-originality-of-my-work)